# Importing CSV files into R

Tags: r

I am trying to import the CSV file directly into my R with the following code:

```
url <- "https://www.kaggle.com/zusmani/us-mass-shootings-last-50-years/downloads/us-mass-shootings-last-50-years.zip/4"


temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, temp)
citibike <- read.csv(unz(temp, "Mass-Shootings-Dataset-Ver-5.csv"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
unlink(temp)
```

However I am receiving the following error message:

```
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot open zip file 'C:\Users\corey\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCMd1pT\file4084193345f6'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you can download the zip file properly? When I try to download it via web browser, the page showed me an auth. layer (Use your Kaggle username or email). I think you can't even download the zip file to your computer. Because the error you face tells it.

Comment: So it seems like an account is required to download files, how can I log in to the site using R? That might solve the issue.

Comment: The downloaded file is a HTML file, and not a zip file. That's it your error: `cannot open zip file`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [kaggler](https://github.com/mkearney/kaggler) to log in.

It also provides functions to get the data and the datasets.